# In WooCommerce Add new input field under shipping details for all orders which shows only for Admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried a lot trying to get an input field under shipping details for all orders to show only for admin. But when I am browsing on the internet for that, I am getting plugins which show input box for both customer and admin.

I found this [link](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) which might work. But I need to know what files are to be changed according to this link.

If you think this doesn't work, give me your own suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to update that tutorial for WooCommerce 3.0, but in order to show the data to only admins you just need some conditional logic to test whether the user has the correct capabilities... and WordPress happens to have [`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) to do just that. `manage_plugins` is a capability you can test that typically only admins have, so should serve your purpose.

```
// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){ 
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_plugins' ) { ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Extra Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php // get the order id with backcompatibility
            $order_id = defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) && version_compare( WC_VERSION, $version, '>=' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Some field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_some_field', true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Another field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_another_field', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

This is only one of the functions I had in my tutorial, but you'd do pretty much the same with the others.

Comment: Can you give me little more details like in which file I should update code and which part of the code is that?

Comment: You should write your own plugin for your site's custom code. You can use this [generator] to create the plugin for you. Then this code would go in the plugin's main file.